# SocketChannel. invalid stream header: 00000000

Tags: java, serialization, nio, bytebuffer, socketchannel

I want to serialize 'Message' object, I can successfully transfer it as bytes array through socketChannel. After that, I change the object's properties (so that it may have larger size), and then there's a problem in sending object back to the client.
Once I try to obtain the object on the client side, I get an exception, it occurs when I deserealize Message obj in getResponse() method:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
```

But, somehow, this applies only for the first client (After the exception is thrown, connection with the first client is over) and when I start a new client (not closing server) I can successfully transfer the object back and forth, furthermore, it works for any new clients.

This is my minimal debuggable version:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    private SocketChannel server;

    public void start() throws IOException {
        try {
            server = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
            server.configureBlocking(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Server isn't responding");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner scRequest = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scState = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter request:");
        String request = scRequest.nextLine();

        while (!request.equals("exit")) {
            try {
                // In my actual project class Person is a way different (But it's still a POJO)
                // I included it here to make sure I can get it back after sending to the server
                System.out.println("Enter a number:");
                Person person = new Person(scState.nextInt());
                sendRequest(request, person);

                System.out.println("\nEnter request:");
                request = scRequest.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        stop();
    }

    public void sendRequest(String sMessage, Person person) {
        Message message = new Message(sMessage, person);
        ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(message));
        try {
            server.write(requestBuffer);
            requestBuffer.clear();
            getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Connection lost");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void getResponse() throws Exception {
        ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 64);

        int read = server.read(responseBuffer);
        responseBuffer.clear();
        if(read == -1) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[responseBuffer.limit()];
        responseBuffer.get(bytes);

        Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        server.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.start();
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

import java.io.*;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Server {

    public void start() throws IOException {

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
        serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
        serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        System.out.println("Server started");

        while (true) {
            selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selectedKeys.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iter.next();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    register(selector, serverSocket);
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    try {
                        getRequest(key);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getRequest(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
        int read = client.read(requestBuffer);
        requestBuffer.clear();

        if(read == -1) {
            key.cancel();
            throw new Exception("Client disconnected at: " +
                    ((SocketChannel) key.channel()).socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[requestBuffer.limit()];
        requestBuffer.get(bytes);

        Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
        sendResponse(client, message);
    }

    private void sendResponse(SocketChannel client, Message message) throws IOException {

        message.setResult("Some result");

        ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(message));
        while (responseBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            client.write(responseBuffer);
        }
        responseBuffer.clear();
    }

    private void register(Selector selector, ServerSocketChannel serverSocket) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        System.out.println("New client at: " + client.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Server().start();
    }
}
```

I try to send this object as a bytes array:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Message implements Serializable {

    private String command;
    private Person person;
    private String result;

    public Message(String command, Person person) {
        this.command = command;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }
    public void setCommand(String executedCommand) {
        this.command = executedCommand;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Formatter()
                .format("Command: %s\nAttached object: %s\nResult: %s",
                        command, person, result)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I include instance of this class inside Message obj:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private final int state;

    public Person(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person state: " + state;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong, hope for your help.

UPD: I used 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' dependency to serialize an object into bytes array

Comment: I see no minimal debuggable version here: `Person` and `Message` are missing, field `server` in class `Client` is missing, field `controller` in class `ServerTerminal` is missing. I also cannot see any `main` method(s) showing how you start client and server. This is why you did not receive any answers so far, despite the bounty.

Comment: @kriegaex why all those classes matter? The problem is in transferring the object and I'm pretty sure the initial problem concerns buffers behaviour. I really thought the problem lied on surface

Comment: They matter because without them your sample code does not compile, without compilation I cannot run it and without running it I cannot help you debug it. You called your code a minimal debuggable sample, but unfortunately that is a false statement. The sample is smaller than minimal.

Comment: Look, I want to help you here. So please take my advice and learn how to ask a good question by means of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I am sure if your problem was reproducible, you would get the answer you are looking for quickly. But for now your sample classes are just pseudo code. Even without regard of the missing classes, the code uses two fields which are not present in the class. You are deliberately hiding information because you think you know where the problem is. How can you be so sure? And why make it more difficult to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @kriegaex ok, I'll try to remake the question, so that it's easier to find the problem. And thank you

Comment: @kriegaex now you can see the "working" version

Comment: Thanks, this is great, now I can run both client and server. I cannot reproduce your problem, though, I am not getting any `SerializationException`. I am starting the server first, then a client, enter something like "foo" as a request and 11 as a number and get normal console output as a response. Do I have to do anything special in order to provoke the error? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @kriegaex thank you for testing. I'm using java 8. I only get the exception after I send the first request to the server, after that it works as expected for any new requests. Also, I get the problem when I change buffers initial size in Client.sendResponse()  and Server.getRequest() methods (e.g. from 64*1024^2 to 1024^2) - but in that case, I get error every time. Now I'm really confused

Comment: Ah okay, in your sample code the buffer sizes for client and server are different. If I use 64M or 1M on both sides, I can reproduce the problem. I will be busy for the rest of the evening, but I guess tomorrow I can take a look.

Comment: You would be far better off losing the `SocketChannel` and the Apache stuff and just using `Sockets` and `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` directly. Then at least you can see exacftly what's going on. It's near enough to impossible to combine non-blocking mode with Serialization that it doesn't matter. I wouldn't attempt it and I'm a 24-year Java programmer.

Comment: @user207421 thank you for advice, I'll definitely take it into account

Comment: @user207421, I had thoughts not unlike yours, reading the code and also checking what the Apache library does internally, i.e. using a byte buffer, then a byte array, then a byte-array-based object in-/output stream. So basically, data are converted to a byte array only to be used in a pseudo stream and be converted back to byte arrays, only to be written into yet another stream (or channel, what the heck) and on the receiver's side the reverse. If performance is not a big issue, it should be okay though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Java NIO channels before, so I am not an expert. But I found out several things:

**General:**

- In order to debug your code, it is helpful to use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of just `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`.

**Client:**

- `SocketChannel server` in the client should be configured as blocking, otherwise it might read 0 bytes because there is no server response yet, which causes your problem.
- You should always call `ByteBuffer.clear()` **before** reading something, not afterwards.
- After reading, the position in the byte buffer has to be reset to 0 via `responseBuffer.position(0)` before calling `get(byte[])`, otherwise it will read undefined bytes **after** the ones just read.
- You should size your byte arrays according to the number of bytes read, not the byte buffer size. It might work the other way around, but it is inefficient.

**Server:**

- You should always call `ByteBuffer.clear()` **before** reading something, not afterwards.
- After reading, the position in the byte buffer has to be reset to 0 via `responseBuffer.position(0)` before calling `get(byte[])`, otherwise it will read undefined bytes **after** the ones just read.
- When catching exceptions during `getRequest(key)` calls, you should close the corresponding channel, otherwise after a client disconnects the server will indefinitely try to read from it, spamming your console log with error messages. My modification handles that case and also prints a nice log message telling which client (remote socket address) was closed.

**Caveat:** There is nothing in your code dealing with the situation that a request or response written into the channel on the one side is bigger than the maximum `ByteBuffer` size on the other side. Similarly, in theory a (de)serialised `byte[]` could also end up being bigger than the byte buffer.

Here are my diffs:

```
Index: src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Client.java
===================================================================
--- a/src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Client.java (revision Staged)
+++ b/src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Client.java (date 1612321383172)
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
   public void start() throws IOException {
     try {
       server = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
-      server.configureBlocking(false);
+      server.configureBlocking(true);
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Server isn't responding");
@@ -56,22 +56,24 @@
       getResponse();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
-      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
+      e.printStackTrace();
+//      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       System.err.println("Connection lost");
       System.exit(0);
     }
   }
 
   public void getResponse() throws Exception {
-    ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 64);
+    ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
+    responseBuffer.clear();
 
     int read = server.read(responseBuffer);
-    responseBuffer.clear();
     if (read == -1) {
-      throw new Exception();
+      throw new Exception("EOF, cannot read server response");
     }
 
-    byte[] bytes = new byte[responseBuffer.limit()];
+    byte[] bytes = new byte[read];
+    responseBuffer.position(0);
     responseBuffer.get(bytes);
 
     Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
```

```
Index: src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Server.java
===================================================================
--- a/src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Server.java (revision Staged)
+++ b/src/main/java/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/q65890087/Server.java (date 1612323386278)
@@ -35,7 +35,11 @@
             getRequest(key);
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
-            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
+            e.printStackTrace();
+//            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
+            SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
+            System.err.println("Closing client connection at: " + client.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
+            client.close();
           }
         }
         iter.remove();
@@ -45,15 +49,16 @@
 
   private void getRequest(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
     SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
-    ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 64);
+    ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
+    requestBuffer.clear();
     int read = client.read(requestBuffer);
-    requestBuffer.clear();
     if (read == -1) {
       key.cancel();
       throw new Exception("Client disconnected at: " +
         ((SocketChannel) key.channel()).socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
     }
-    byte[] bytes = new byte[requestBuffer.limit()];
+    byte[] bytes = new byte[read];
+    requestBuffer.position(0);
     requestBuffer.get(bytes);
     Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
     sendResponse(client, message);
```

Just for completeness' sake, here are the full classes after I changed them:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

  private SocketChannel server;

  public void start() throws IOException {
    try {
      server = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
      server.configureBlocking(true);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Server isn't responding");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner scRequest = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scState = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter request:");
    String request = scRequest.nextLine();

    while (!request.equals("exit")) {
      try {
        // In my actual project class Person is a way different (But it's still a POJO)
        // I included it here to make sure I can get it back after sending to the server
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        Person person = new Person(scState.nextInt());
        sendRequest(request, person);

        System.out.println("\nEnter request:");
        request = scRequest.nextLine();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    stop();
  }

  public void sendRequest(String sMessage, Person person) {
    Message message = new Message(sMessage, person);
    ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(message));
    try {
      server.write(requestBuffer);
      requestBuffer.clear();
      getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
//      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      System.err.println("Connection lost");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void getResponse() throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
    responseBuffer.clear();

    int read = server.read(responseBuffer);
    if (read == -1) {
      throw new Exception("EOF, cannot read server response");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[read];
    responseBuffer.position(0);
    responseBuffer.get(bytes);

    Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    System.out.println(message);
  }

  public void stop() throws IOException {
    server.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.start();
  }
}
```

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Server {
  public void start() throws IOException {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
    serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
    serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    System.out.println("Server started");

    while (true) {
      selector.select();
      Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
      Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selectedKeys.iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = iter.next();
        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
          register(selector, serverSocket);
        }
        if (key.isReadable()) {
          try {
            getRequest(key);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            System.err.println("Closing client connection at: " + client.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
            client.close();
          }
        }
        iter.remove();
      }
    }
  }

  private void getRequest(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
    requestBuffer.clear();
    int read = client.read(requestBuffer);
    if (read == -1) {
      key.cancel();
      throw new Exception("Client disconnected at: " +
        ((SocketChannel) key.channel()).socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[read];
    requestBuffer.position(0);
    requestBuffer.get(bytes);
    Message message = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    sendResponse(client, message);
  }

  private void sendResponse(SocketChannel client, Message message) throws IOException {
    message.setResult("Some result");
    ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(SerializationUtils.serialize(message));
    while (responseBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
      client.write(responseBuffer);
    }
    responseBuffer.clear();
  }

  private void register(Selector selector, ServerSocketChannel serverSocket) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
    client.configureBlocking(false);
    client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    System.out.println("New client at: " + client.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Server().start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spent pretty much time on this, but didn't even understand the real causes.

Comment: Without the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I would not have been able to debug this. You did yourself the greatest favour by providing it. As for debugging, I used a mixture of logging output (also full stack traces for exceptions) and stepping through the code in a debugger, investigating what was sent and received on both sides.